# Generate unique combinations of rows where each row is treated as an individual split by a variable

Tags: r

I want to treat each row as a single element when creating unique combinations. Each combination should be between a Left and a Right only. So the first row in the example can be combined with the last two rows only, and the second row can be combined with the last two rows only.

Previously someone helped me with the following code, but it only creates combinations by rows when I need it between Left and Right rows.:

```
combs <- combn(1:nrow(df1), 2)
do.call(rbind, Map(function(i,j) cbind(df1[i,],df1[j,]), combs[1,], combs[2,]))
```

Say I have a dataframe with the following:

```
Side    Var1    Var2
Left     b        a
Left     a        b
Right    b        a
Right    a        b
```

and I want the following combinations in a single dataframe:

```
Side    Var1    Var2    Side     Var1   Var2
Left    b        a      Right      b        a
Left    b        a      Right      a        b
Left    a        b      Right      b        a
Left    a        b      Right      a        b
```

Comment: something like `library(data.table); setDT(data); expand.grid(unique(data[Side=="Left",.(Var1, Var2)]), unique(data[Side=="Right",.(Var1, Var2)]))`?

Comment: can you explain more in detail the logic you'd like to gain your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a  more elegant way, but this gives the desired output.

First, we count how many 'unique' variables we have
    #assuming this is the same for Var1 and Var2

```
n_vars <- length(unique(dat$Var1))
```

Then we create a datafram of combinations of indices using expand.grid

```
#create indices
indices <- expand.grid(1:n_vars,1:n_vars)
```

And use those to create our output:

```
#create sub-dataframes
left <- dat[dat$Side=="Left",]
right <- dat[dat$Side=="Right",]

#cbind them together, using our indices to select rows
res <- cbind(left[indices[,1],],right[indices[,2],])
res
# Side Var1 Var2  Side Var1 Var2
# 1   Left    b    a Right    b    a
# 2   Left    a    b Right    b    a
# 1.1 Left    b    a Right    a    b
# 2.1 Left    a    b Right    a    b
```

Comment: So far so good. I'll keep playing around with your code and see if it works with the rest of my code.

Comment: Just one more issue to workout. Is it possible to re-arrange the new data.frame where in each combination var 1 will be next to var 1, var 2 next to var 2, etc. That when when accessing the data I can do data[,i][x] and data[,i+1][x] to access both var 1 in each combination for other processing. 

I'm working on an incredibly annoying project where I have to transform data from a standardized form that makes life incredibly difficult.

Comment: nm, pretty simple to do using order and name. I really need to buy an R book. :P

Comment: Your code is breaking when dealing with numerous columns. Any ideas?

Comment: Update your example? I have no idea what you're trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified from Heroka to account for different amount of left and rights and reorders so each left/right variables are next to each other:

```
n_varsleft <- length(unique(sortdata[sortdata$Side == 'left',][,1]))
n_varsright <- length(unique(sortdata[sortdata$Side == 'right',][,1]))
indices <- expand.grid(1:n_varsleft, 1:n_varsright)
left <- sortdata[sortdata$Side == 'left',]
right <- sortdata[sortdata$Side == 'right',]
res <- cbind(left[indices[,1],], right[indices[,2],])
res <- res[,order(names(res))]
```